# Enemy vs Player function - Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

So I'm teaching myself python3 and I am creating a text-based adventure game. The issue I am running into right now is dealing with the fight sequence between the player and the enemy. I have created variables for the enemy to randomly pick from an array, their health and attack stats. This is working, however trying to essentially do (enemy health - player attack) has been a challenge.

Here is what I started with, which worked until trying to plug it into the fight function.

```
 enemy_health = [75, 80, 85, 90, 100, 110]
    enemy_calchealth = random.choices(
        enemy_health, weights=(5, 30, 20, 30, 10, 5), k=1)
enemy_attack = [15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
    enemy_calcattack = random.choices(
        enemy_attack, weights=(5, 30, 20, 30, 10, 5), k=1)
```

Then I tried creating a class for the enemy, since I had already created a class for the player.

```
class Creature:
    enemy_health = [75, 80, 85, 90, 100, 110]

    def creature_health_gen(self):
        self.enemy_health_calc = random.choices(
            self.enemy_health, weights=(5, 30, 20, 30, 10, 5), k=1)

    enemy_attack = [15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]

    def creature_attack_gen(self):
        self.enemy_attack_calc = random.choices(
            self.enemy_attack, weights=(5, 30, 20, 30, 10, 5), k=1)
```

And I call these functions to trigger the random stat generation

```
creature.creature_health_gen()
creature.creature_attack_gen()
```

Here is the function I tried to create the fight between the player and the enemy

```
def fight():
    choice7 = input('Take first swing? (Y/N)')
    if choice7.lower() in yes:
        creature.enemy_health_calc - player.add_attack
        print(f'The creature took {player.add_attack} damage. Their health is now {creature.enemy_calchealth}')
    else:
        creature.enemy_health_calc - player.attack
        print(f'The creature took {player.attack} damage. Their health is now {creature.enemy_health_calc}')
```

When I try and run this I get an attribute error - `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'creature_health_gen'`

Thank you in advance for all help and suggestions

Comment: Hi you need to provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You haven't defined ```player```, and missed some steps, also provide the full error stack.

Comment: I think the reason you see this is misspelling some objects. With the code you have provided, no `creature` function/class can be found. But in the error, there is a function named `creature`. Maybe providing the full code can help

Answer (score 0):

`AttributeError` means you tried to look for a function or a variable inside a class that does not exist. for example, if i write `"".foo()` then i would get an attribute error since "" doesn't have a function named foo.

according to the error you got, it seems that creature is actually a function, not a class. so either creature is actually a function and you meant to use `creature().creature_health_gen`. or that at some point of the code, you changed creature to be a diffrent value.

id love to help you out more with this, since i am also self taught and i understand how tough it is, but i can't really do much with just parts of the code. if you could send either the full code, or at least every point where you set the value of creature then i could help you out further.